# What is the time complexity of below string matching program?

Tags: python, arrays, string, substring, any

t= total string and s= test string if its present in t

```
  t=input()                      #main string
  s=input()                       #check for substring
  print(any(s==t[i:i+len(s)] for i in range(len(t)-len(s))))
```

the give time complexity is `O( (s)(t-s) )` but i did't understand how

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your complexity is more `O(len(s).(len(t)-len(s)))` than `O((s)(t-s))` because

1. The loop size is `len(t)-len(s)` because of the `range(len(t)-len(s))`
2. Then each round loop does `s == t[i:i+len(s)]` which is a string comparison where both part have a length of `len(s)`, so `len(s)` char to compare

Multiply them : `len(s).(len(t)-len(s))`